# Did drag& drop from Outlook stop working recently?

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop, visual-foxpro

my program is seeing the drop event but can't get a valid format response. This changed in the last week or so (i.e. working code that used to see a format of 1 (text message) with the name of the attachment being dropped).

dragging from 64bit outlook build 13901.20336 to a 32 bit VFP9 .exe.

drag and dropping between outlook windows (i.e. dragging attachments from email to email) still works.

in the oleDRAGDROP event i have code that tests for known formats and then drops through to search between -64000 to +64000. Nothing is being recognised.
e.g.

```
do case
  case odataobject.getformat(-16378)
    m.lctext = odataobject.getdata(-16378)
  case odataobject.getformat(15)
    *
    *
  case odataobject.getformat(1)
    *
  otherwise
    for i= -64000 to 64000
     if odataobject.getformat(m.i)
       m.lctext = odataobject.getdata(m.i)
     exit
    endif
  next
endcase
```

n

edit:
updated outlook (build 13901.20462 click to run) and problem persists.

for now if my oledragdrop code fails to get a valid .getformat() it assumes dragged from outlook and fetches the first PDF, JPG or PNG attachment on the currently selected outlook item that isn't an embedded image.

Not ideal but probably what is expected about 90% of the time.

Comment: What code do you have for handling the drag&drop operations?

Comment: working code (until a week ago) that loops around doing a odataobject.getformat(). as last resort it loops from -64000 to +64000 but as i said until a week ago it would see the attachment filename as format 1.

Answer (score 0):

odataobject.GETFORMAT("FileGroupDescriptor")
and
odataobject.GETDATA("FileGroupDescriptor")

are still working.

So i just have to extract the filename from that structure and carry on as before.